# change fontstyle of rdlc report in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

i have 10 column in rdlc report.i want to change column value style in bold for specific cell that start with "G" like i have value "G 100".
i tried this =iif(fields!myfield.value.tostring().startwith("G"),"Normal","Bold") but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because you're using `IIF` wrong. It should be

```
=iif(fields!myfield.value.ToString().StartsWith("G"),"Bold","Normal")
```

That being said, you should see all other fields in bold with your statement... Are you sure you used this on the `Font.Weight` property of the value cell, not the entire column? It would cause random results if you used this on the entire column, as all cells in the column would be formatted according to the last rendered cell.